# How to Evaluate this Integral $\int \frac{\cos 6x+\cos 8x}{1+2\cos 5x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Evaluate the following integral

$$I=\int \frac{\cos 6x+\cos 8x}{1+2\cos 5x}dx$$

### My work

I tried to change $\cos x$ into $\sin x$ and try to substitute.
But I am not getting it ...

Comment: brute force would be weierstrass substition

Comment: @tired: What is that substitution. Can you write it down? :)

Comment: can you use "google"?

Comment: @tired: Of course I can but it would be good to see it below this question! :)

Comment: Wolfram does it but makes a huge mess of it. Have you written it down correctly as its not pretty. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%28cos%286x%29%2Bcos%288x%29%29%2F%281%2B2Cos%285x%29%29&dataset=&equal=Submit

Comment: @tired: I just found out that you mean **tangent half angel substitution**! But it won't work here as it is used for rational functions of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ only. :) But here we have $\cos 8x$, $\cos 6x$, $\cos 5x$!

Comment: it works but it becomes very ugly, that's the reason why i call this brute force!

Comment: @tired: Yes you are right! :) We can convert $\cos nx$ to $\cos x$. :)

Comment: is there any other way to do this? Because this is a school book question..

Answer (score 4):

Here, I will try to explain the **process** of integration. I did the computations in MAPLE so even don't think of doing this lengthy calculations by hand! :) You can download the [MAPLE file from here](http://pc.cd/lNErtalK).

$1.$ **Convert multiple angels to single angles** using the following identities

$$\eqalign{
  & \cos \left( {8x} \right) = 128\cos {\left( x \right)^8} - 256\cos {\left( x \right)^6} + 160\cos {\left( x \right)^4} - 32\cos {\left( x \right)^2} + 1  \cr 
  & \cos \left( {6x} \right) = 32\cos {(x)^6} - 48\cos {(x)^4} + 18\cos {(x)^2} - 1  \cr 
  & \cos \left( {5x} \right) = 16\cos {(x)^5} - 20\cos {(x)^3} + 5\cos (x) \cr} $$

and rewrite the integrand

$$f = {{128\cos {{\left( x \right)}^8} - 224\cos {{\left( x \right)}^6} + 112\cos {{\left( x \right)}^4} - 14\cos {{\left( x \right)}^2}} \over {1 + 32\cos {{\left( x \right)}^5} - 40\cos {{\left( x \right)}^3} + 10\cos \left( x \right)}}$$

$2.$ Use the **tangent half angle substitution**

$$\eqalign{
  & u = \tan \left( {{x \over 2}} \right)  \cr 
  & dx = {2 \over {1 + {u^2}}}du  \cr 
  & \cos \left( x \right) = {{1 - {u^2}} \over {1 + {u^2}}} \cr} $$

Hence your integral will be

$$\eqalign{
  & g(u) = f\left( {x(u)} \right)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = {{ - 4{u^{16}} + 368{u^{14}} - 4368{u^{12}} + 16016{u^{10}} - 24024{u^8} + 16016{u^6} - 4368{u^4} + 368{u^2} - 4} \over {\left( {{u^2} - 3} \right){{\left( {{u^2} + 1} \right)}^4}\left( {{u^8} - 92{u^6} + 134{u^4} - 28{u^2} + 1} \right)}}  \cr 
  & h(u) = g(u){2 \over {1 + {u^2}}}  \cr 
  & I = \int {f(x)dx}  = \int {h(u)du}  \cr} $$

$3.$ The hard part is to use **partial fractions** to decompose $h(u)$ into

$$\eqalign{
  & h(u) = \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} - 3} \right)} {R \over {30\left( {u - R} \right)}} + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}  - {2 \over {{{\left( {u - R} \right)}^2}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}  - {{4R} \over {{{\left( {u - R} \right)}^3}}} + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)} {4 \over {{{\left( {u - R} \right)}^4}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^8} - 92{x^6} + 134{x^4} - 28{x^2} + 1} \right)} {{ - {{71} \over {1920}}{R^7} + {{1307} \over {384}}{R^5} - {{3263} \over {640}}{R^3} + {{2293} \over {1920}}R} \over {u - R}} \cr} $$

$4.$ Now, **integrate** the decomposed $h(u)$. As you can see, the last term  with eighth degree polynomial which does have 8 real distinct roots that are hard to compute is a disaster. This makes the final result a little ugly given by MAPLE or Wolfram-Alpha! So sometimes to compute an integral you may give those computing monsters some directions manually to obtain a more beautiful and tidier final result!

$$\eqalign{
  & I = \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} - 3} \right)} {{R\ln \left( {u - R} \right)} \over {30}} + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)} {2 \over {u - R}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\, + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)} {{2R} \over {{{\left( {u - R} \right)}^2}}} + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}  - {4 \over {3{{\left( {u - R} \right)}^3}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\, + \mathop \sum \limits_{R = RootOf\left( {{x^8} - 92{x^6} + 134{x^4} - 28{x^2} + 1} \right)} \left( { - {{71} \over {1920}}{R^7} + {{1307} \over {384}}{R^5} - {{3263} \over {640}}{R^3} + {{2293} \over {1920}}R} \right)\ln \left( {u - R} \right) \cr} $$

As you could see, the integrals to be evaluated after partial fraction decomposition were so easy; however, the process was frustrating and brutal! :)

Comment: (+1) ,nice exposition of why this integral is a piece of *peep* ;-)

Comment: @tired: Yeah! :D

Comment: +1 for this answer but I am not accepting this answer only because i am expecting a short answer. Is it possible??

Comment: @H.R.and can you send the mapple file to my email id daviddgl@yahoo.in since pCloud is blocked in my university web.

Comment: @gloom: I don't think that there is a short answer! :) Somehow I am sure about it! I sent it to your e-mail.